# Is "Did you do" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is did you do in the following sentence grammatical?

> What did you do during the summer?

Comment: Notice that even "What did you last summer?" is accepted in some way in informal English.However, I wouldn't recommend anybody use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a proper use of did you do. "Did" can be used as a way to ask a sentence and the verb in here is "do".